# Gauss Theorem and Faraday's Law

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

I'm studying magnetic fields and I have a big problem. The Gauss theorem states that the magnetic flux through a closed surface is null since the line of flux enter and exit from it in the same amount. However, the Faraday law talks about the flux linkage with a surface which can be not null in case, for example, the magnetic field is not constant in time. Why is not null as well, since it is the flux through a surface?

Answer (score 3):

Faraday's law talks about the flux piercing through an **open** surface, while Gauss' law for magnetic fields is for a **closed** surface.

Comment: Please can you give me an example? If I am correct, broadly speaking, a closed surface is a surface in which you cannot go from a side to another without crossing it. So a circumference, in which some lines of flux go through is closed or opened?

Comment: Here's a Wikipedia article I think might [help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Closed_surfaces.) Just as an example, imagine a sphere--that's a closed surface. Now imagine a sphere with a pinprick-sized hole in it--that's an open surface. A circumference is open, so is [this](http://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/nGQbA2jwkWI/sddefault.jpg)

Comment: Now the difference between closed and opened surfaces is very clear, but why the flux through this two types of surfaces is different? I have to clear up my mind: for sake of simplicity I consider the flux of a fluid, I know that the flux is a vectorial quantity so entering - exiting = 0 (closed surface), but means that there is no net effect or no flux at all?

Comment: Magnetic field lines are always in closed loops. If the surface is closed, a field line that comes in must also go out. An open surface does not carry such restrictions. In a closed surface, it does not mean that there is no flux at all, simply no **net** flux.

Comment: So should not be the derivative of the flux over time to be null and the flux constant, if the net flux is null?

Comment: The derivative of flux through a closed surface?

Comment: The change of the flux over time, is it nonsense?

Answer (score 3):

The two concerned equations

\begin{align}\mathbf \nabla \times \mathbf E  &= -\frac{\partial{\mathbf B}}{\partial t}\tag 1 \\ \mathbf \nabla \cdot \mathbf  B &= 0\tag 2\end{align}

are conveying totally different meanings.

While the former $(1)$ correlates the circulation of the *induced* electric field with the negative time rate of change of the associated magnetic field; the later viz. $(2)$ says that the divergence of magnetic field is essentially zero.

Let's come to the present context where OP seems to confused with the integral forms of the equation:
The integral forms respectively are:

\begin{align} \int_\textrm C \mathbf E \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf s &= -\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\, \underbrace{\color{red}{\int _\mathrm S\mathbf B\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf a}}_{\Phi\equiv\, \textrm{magnetic flux}}\tag 1 \\ \underbrace{\int_\mathrm S\mathbf  B\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf a}_{\textrm{flux through}\,\color{red}{\textrm{closed surface}}} &= 0\tag 2\end{align}

OP can see the distinct red marked term in the first equation; the later doesn't talk like that.
The possible misinterpretation could be averted if OP transforms the differential form to integral form keeping in mind the **Gauss' or Divergence theorem** and the **Stokes' Theorem.**

Comment: Very clear answer and the difference between the two quantities is clearer. I realized that my problem is on the physical meaning of flux, I read some definitions which were usefulness. Thinking of a fluid and considering a cylindrical tube,  the flux is the flow rate per unit of surface; now without any internal generation or withdrawal for the Gauss theorem it should be null: why? there is still matter flowing in and out from it.